# getting error SyntaxError: invalid syntax --> record_dict2["upper_band"].append(trade_dict["upper_band"])

Tags: python

I'm getting an error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax -->
>   record_dict2["upper_band"].append(trade_dict["upper_band"])

I couldn't understand where the error is. What I'm trying to do is append data to a list which is keyed in `record_dict2`.

```
record_dict2 = {"date":[],
                "spread":[],
                "rolling_mean":[],
                "rolling_std":[],
                "upper_band":[],
                "upper_band2":[],
                "upper_band3":[],
                "lower_band":[],
                "lower_band2":[],
                "lower_band3":[],
                "short_con_1":[],
                "short_con_2":[],
                "long_con_1":[],
                "long_con_2":[],
                "trade_exit_time":[],
                "pnl":[]}


trade_dict = backtesting(df,model,window,start,current_date,rolling_window,deviations)
trade_exit_date_time = record_dict["trade_exit_time"]

# append all the info 
record_dict2["date"].append(trade_dict["date"]) 
record_dict2["spread"].append(trade_dict["spread"])
record_dict2["rolling_mean"].append(trade_dict["rolling_mean"])
record_dict2["rolling_std"].append(trade_dict["rolling_std"]
record_dict2["upper_band"].append(trade_dict["upper_band"])
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis/bracket on the line above.

Comment: how come u spotted so easily I was trying to see it but still was blinded

Comment: One thing to know is that these syntax errors often point to the following line.